# Missing Orc-0.4.6 when configure script is run

Tags: ubuntu, package, gstreamer

I was trying to get all the plugins for gstreamer installed, and when I installed the gst-plugins-ugly, it showed a list of plugins that would not be built and said that Orc was not found.
Message:

```
configure: *** Plug-ins with dependencies that will NOT be built:
a52dec
amrnb
amrwbdec
cdio
dvdreadsrc
lame
mad
mpeg2dec
sid
twolame
x264

configure: *** Orc acceleration disabled.  Requires Orc >= 0.4.6, which was
           not found.  Slower code paths will be used.
```

I tried finding Orc, but could not find anything. Liborc I found and installed, but that is version 0.4.0. Does anyone know where I can find orc? I am running ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The releases are now availble here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/orc/

Or get the upstream source code from git git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/orc

Comment: This repository seems to be out of date now. Use this instead: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/orc/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having the issues right now in ubuntu 18.04

> apt-get install liborc-0.4-dev

install above should get the liborc files and the related orc-0.4.pc installed so that pkg-config picks it up.